# Using 1 Zune Library from two PCs?

Tags: sync, music, podcasts, zune, zune-software

I use the Zune PC software to manage my music/podcast library and I'd like to have one Library that I can use from two different computers. Has anyone managed/tried to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** I would recommend setting up your own home server, store your music on it, and then tell the Zune Software where to find the music (e.g. your server)...some excellent home solutions are available, such as [Amahi Home Server](http://www.amahi.org/) (free, Fedora Linux based), or [Windows Home Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/windowshomeserver/default.mspx)...

**2)** The other thing you could do, if you have a home network setup, is to store your music on either PC, then enable "File and Printer Sharing", and point your Zune Software to those network folders...that way, you can use the music on either PC...

Comment: I'd definitely recommend #1 if you're in a networked environment. Some routers even have a USB port on them, so you can just drop an external hard drive on the router and share it to all the computers in your home.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the optimal solution but I think you could use [DropBox](https://www.getdropbox.com/referrals/NTEyNzUwNDM5) in both of your computer and put the library on a DropBox folder. This way, any change will be sync to the other computer.

Comment: Hmmm, that might work. I'll try it tonight

Comment: The problem with that is that dropbox only has 2GB of storage that is free, so your music collection would have to be pretty compact in order to use dropbox...it also takes a while to sync music back and forth between computers...